# final assignment question regarding arrays

Tags: c, arrays

so I'm currently working on my final assignment for my intro to programming class and the two big restrictions we have is we are not allowed to use 2D arrays and we are not allowed to use pointers. Now the assignment is to basically create a poll program, I wanted to have 3 50 element arrays. One for each candidate and one for the states so that I can print the state from the array rather then trying to figure out how to hard code it or something. Is it possible to store words or more specifically the state names in an array without using pointers? So far when I've tried it just returns 1 when I print it

edit

```c
#include<stdio.h>

void votebiden(int*);
void votetrump(int*);



main() {
    char statearray[50];
    statearray[0] = "alabama";
    printf("%s", statearray[1]);



    int votebiden[50] = { 0 };
    int votetrump[50] = { 0 };
    int bidencounter= 0, trumpcounter = 0;



};
```

thats the entirety of my code after rewriting my attempt at the state storing array. what the program ultimately needs to do is print up a menu to allow the user to enter votes for either candidate (fairly simple), to print the total votes for each candidate alongside the votes per state. to list the states where the candidates tied. and to display the states and number of votes where each candidate got the highest and lowest votes.

originally I figured I could do this by storing the state names in each element of an array like I try to do above, but when I go to print the array it either comes back as the single number 1 as opposed to the word I want, or it comes back as garbage.

Comment: Can you show us your code ?

Comment: And remember that you can emulate a two-dimensional array using a one-dimensional array (and the power of math).

Comment: Please define what you mean by "poll program", "candidate", "state", "state names". Give examples. You have code which prints 1, show it please. Try for a [mre] which demonstrates your problem. What do you expect instead of "1"? Why?

Comment: With the information you give, the answer to your question is "Yes". Would you like to give more details and explanation? That would increase your chances enormously, for an answer which actually helps you.

Comment: `void votebiden(int*)` There's a pointer! You can't assign multiple characters to a single element of a `char` array as in `statearray[0] = "alabama";`. To avoid 2d arrays and pointers I would probably use an array of `struct`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all the names in a single dimensional array, padded to the length of the longest states with `'\0'`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char statesarray[] = {
        'A','l','a','b','a','m','a', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'A','l','a','s','k','a', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'A','r','i','z','o','n','a', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'A','r','k','a','n','s','a','s', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'C','a','l','i','f','o','r','n','i','a', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'C','o','l','o','r','a','d','o', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'C','o','n','n','e','c','t','i','c','u','t', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'D','e','l','a','w','a','r','e', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'F','l','o','r','i','d','a', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'G','e','o','r','g','i','a', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'H','a','w','a','i','i', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'I','d','a','h','o', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'I','l','l','i','n','o','i','s', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'I','n','d','i','a','n','a', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'I','o','w','a', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'K','a','n','s','a','s', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'K','e','n','t','u','c','k','y', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'L','o','u','i','s','i','a','n','a', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'M','a','i','n','e', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'M','a','r','y','l','a','n','d', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'M','a','s','s','a','c','h','u','s','e','t','t','s', 0 , 0 ,
        'M','i','c','h','i','g','a','n', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'M','i','n','n','e','s','o','t','a', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'M','i','s','s','i','s','s','i','p','p','i', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'M','i','s','s','o','u','r','i', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'M','o','n','t','a','n','a', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'N','e','b','r','a','s','k','a', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'N','e','v','a','d','a', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'N','e','w',' ','H','a','m','p','s','h','i','r','e', 0 , 0 ,
        'N','e','w',' ','J','e','r','s','e','y', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'N','e','w',' ','M','e','x','i','c','o', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'N','e','w',' ','Y','o','r','k', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'N','o','r','t','h',' ','C','a','r','o','l','i','n','a', 0 ,
        'N','o','r','t','h',' ','D','a','k','o','t','a', 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'O','h','i','o', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'O','k','l','a','h','o','m','a', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'O','r','e','g','o','n', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'P','e','n','n','s','y','l','v','a','n','i','a', 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'R','h','o','d','e',' ','I','s','l','a','n','d', 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'S','o','u','t','h',' ','C','a','r','o','l','i','n','a', 0 ,
        'S','o','u','t','h',' ','D','a','k','o','t','a', 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'T','e','n','n','e','s','s','e','e', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'T','e','x','a','s', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'U','t','a','h', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'V','e','r','m','o','n','t', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'V','i','r','g','i','n','i','a', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'W','a','s','h','i','n','g','t','o','n', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'W','e','s','t',' ','V','i','r','g','i','n','i','a', 0 , 0 ,
        'W','i','s','c','o','n','s','i','n', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,
        'W','y','o','m','i','n','g', 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 };
        // the longest state names are the Carolinas (14 chars + \0)

        //printf("%s\n", statesarray+(15*0)); // Alabama
        for(int i=0; i<50; i++) printf("%s\n", statesarray+(15*i));
        //printf("%s\n", statesarray+(15*49)); // Wyoming
    return 0;
}
```

Although we use offset indexing, which is pointer arithmetic, note that we never use `*`, the dereference (indirection) operator!